# Is it valid to pass the same buffer to the source and destination of a winapi call

Tags: winapi

Is this valid? I thought not but the answer was not readily apparent.

```
long PATH_MAX;
TCHAR* lpszPath;

/* Assign path and PATH_MAX here */

/* Replace the path with a short path */    
GetShortPathName(lpszPath, lpszPath, PATH_MAX);
```

Comment: Do you know that this function is documented?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single general answer for all WinAPI calls; you need to look at the official documentation for each function individually.

For the example you gave (`GetShortPathName()`), its [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364989.aspx) specifically states:

> You can set the `lpszShortPath` parameter to the same value as the
>   `lpszLongPath` parameter; in other words, you can set the output buffer
>   for the short path to the address of the input path string. Always ensure that the `cchBuffer` parameter accurately represents the total size, in `TCHAR`s, of this buffer.

Therefore, it is safe to pass the same value for both path parameters for this particular function.

For other functions, if the documentation does not explicitly permit using the same buffer then you should assume it is not safe.

Comment: Thanks. I know that people think that this is a bad question but I was not sure whether I could assume this in general. Good answer though.

Comment: @xaav: It is a poor question, because even though you claimed, that *"the answer [were] not readily apparent"*, it is, as explained in this answer.

Comment: The reason that I have 3k reputation is because of a question similar in nature to this one except for PHP (which should be outlawed IHMO). The difference is that PHPers are noobs and winapi people are not.

Comment: But it does seem ironic that whether the question is downvoted depends on the language.